# Rename tag [signals]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

Please rename tag [signals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/signals) on Stack Overflow.

This tag's About information begins as follows:

> A signal is a notification to a process that an event occurred. Signals are sometimes described as software interrupts...

People often confuse it for other types of questions however. Like for questions related to Qt signals and slots, for which the tag [qt-signals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt-signals) or [signals-slots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/signals-slots) seems more appropriate. Or they confuse it for questions related to signal processing, for which the tag [signal-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/signal-processing) seems more appropriate.

Perhaps rename the tag [signals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/signals) to [process-signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/process-signal) or to [software-interrupts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/software-interrupts).

Comment: The ambiguity will certainly be resulting in some confusion and waste of time. Perhaps if there were some way for such ambiguous tags, when entered, to offer the approved vocabulary .... ? This feature would, of course, require maintenance, and whether the mods would be prepared to do that I can't say.

Comment: I see I was referring to an extant feature whose existence was unknown to me: [tag synonyms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms).

Comment: That's actually a good thing, @holdenweb. Synonyms should be completely transparent, so you not knowing about them kinda means they're working well. :-) The only time they crop up in the UI is when you try to tag a question something, and then see that tag magically replaced with something else when you submit the question. This can be confusing to people who don't know about synonyms.

Comment: I suppose I was hypothesising that tags might have multiple synonyms, and users entering an ambiguous tag should be asked to select among the alternatives. That would, however, require programming changes